# How to get entire list from just one value in a dictionary key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dictionary and key

```
y_dict[key] = [l_y, u_y, mn, price_min]
```

When I enter

```
print(y_dict)
```

I get this:

```
{4: [4.982755559285482, 6.341688893636068, 5.662222226460774, 5.369999885559082], 22: [5.847999992370606, 7.442909081198954, 6.645454536784779, 6.230000019073486], 60: [4.826400032043457, 6.142690949873491, 5.484545490958474, 5.019999980926514]}
```

I only want to get the price_min which lists these numbers 5.3699 , 6.2300 and 5.0199 so what I want to print is this:

```
5.369999885559082, 6.230000019073486, 5.019999980926514
```

When I enter

```
print(y_dict[price_min])
```

I only get the last price_min item in the list 5.019999980926514. How do I get the entire price_min lists instead of just the last item?

Comment: Your title says you want all values from one key. But it sounds like you want one value from all keys.

Comment: You seem to be confused between lists and keys. `y_dict` is a dict, but the values are lists.

Comment: Edited the question to correct the mixup between values, lists and keys for future reference. Thank you for the clarification @Barmar . New to coding so your patience and explanation is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably just do something like

```
minimums = [val[3] for key, val in y_dict.items()]
```

It'll be stored as an list in the variable `minimums`.

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension.

```
print([item[3] for item in y_dict.values()])
```

BTW, I recommend you store the values as dictionaries, rather than hard-coding list indexes like that.

```
y_dict[key] = {'l_y': l_y, 'u_y': u_y, 'mn': mn, 'price_min': price_min}
```

The list comprehension then becomes:

```
print(*[item['price_min'] for item in y_dict.values()], sep=", ")
```

Comment: The first line that you wrote worked perfectly for me thank you! When I try to store the values as dictionaries rather than hard coding list indexes as you suggested I get an error saying "Variable annotation cannot be combined with tuple unpacking".

Comment: I had a typo in my original answer, try the edited version.